# What is the largest possible length of a string-representation of a float?

Tags: java, floating-point, maxlength

Title pretty much says it all...

I am trying to enforce the maximum length of text input on a form.  One of the fields can be any valid floating-point number.  What would its maximum length be?

For example, for an integer

```
// negative sign makes MIN_VALUE larger than MAX_VALUE
String.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE).length();
```

**UPDATE**

I have tested the following:

```
String.valueOf(-Float.MIN_VALUE).length();
String.valueOf(-Float.MAX_VALUE).length();
String.valueOf( Float.MIN_VALUE).length();
String.valueOf( Float.MAX_VALUE).length();
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
8
13
7
12
```

I'm not convinced that 13 is the maximum length

Comment: Why do you want to check number of characters in string representation of float? WHy can't you use float directly?

Comment: [`-Float.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#MAX_VALUE)?

Comment: @Lokesh To be honest, I don't **need** this. I'm currently just grabbing the input for that field using `Float.valueOf(field.getText())`, and that works fine. But all my other fields are limited to a max length, so I was hoping to do the same for this field.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I have tested `-Float.MAX_VALUE`.  Check my updated Question

Comment: @firyice That's because of the representation, print `Float.MAX_VALUE` to better understand it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun `String.valueOf(Float.MAX_VALUE - .000000000000001).length()` gives me `21` so it can clearly be longer.

Comment: @MarounMaroun ...and I'm wrong. `String.valueOf(Float.MAX_VALUE - .000000000000001f).length()` gives me `12`.  Without the `f` it becomes a double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A maximum length for a float value doesn't make sense.

If you want the user to enter any float value representable by java you want allow thing like

```
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

or even

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.00000000000000000000001
```

Limits for input fields should be based on business needs not on rules like "I have a limit on all other fields".

The "business" rule here so far seems to be "Can be parsed and stored into a float"

Also note that limiting the input length often prevents input (via cut&paste) of stuff that is longer and only becomes valid input after some editing. So it actually reduces usability.

Comment: Thank you for helping me realize the mistake in my 3am thought process.

Answer (score 1):

A counter-example can be provided by simply testing random values until a stable maximum value can be found. A possible problem with this approach is that only local maxima can be found and no exhaustive global maximum.

The result on this PC was:

```
Max. float length: 15 (-1.09045365E-32)
```

Which is a counter-example to your `-Float.MAX_VALUE`.

Sometimes it is useful to know what the maximum length is of `Float.toString()`, in which case this question can be answered.

```
public class FindMaxStringForPrimitive {

  private static final int MAX_PERIOD = 10000; // Number of iterations before
                                               // concluding answer

  public static void main(String... args) {
    maxFloatLength();
  }

  private static void maxFloatLength() {
    final class Test {
      int    r   = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      Random rnd = new Random();
      String max = "";

      boolean fit() {
        return fit(Float.intBitsToFloat(rnd.nextInt()));
      }

      boolean fit(float value) {
        String x = Float.toString(value);
        if (x.length() > r) {
          r = x.length();
          max = x;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
    Test test = new Test();
    int i = 0;
    test.fit(Float.MAX_VALUE);
    test.fit(-Float.MAX_VALUE);
    test.fit(Float.MIN_VALUE);
    test.fit(-Float.MIN_VALUE);
    test.fit(Float.NaN);
    test.fit(Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
    test.fit(Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
    while (i < MAX_PERIOD)
      if (test.fit()) i = 0;
      else
        i++;
    System.out.println("Max. float length: " + test.r + " (" + test.max + ")");
  }

}
```